# Problem animating with geom_sf and gganimate: Error: arguments have different crs

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to animate a plot of changing counts of something in each region of the UK over the course of 10 years.

I have an shapefile of UK regions which can be downloaded from this [URL](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/ons::nuts1-jan-2018-super-generalised-clipped-boundaries-in-the-uk/explore?location=55.225060%2C-3.317654%2C7.44) and loaded using:

```
uk_map <- read_sf(filepath)
```

I have a dataframe of counts that I want to plot for each year:

```
yearCountsAllRegions<-data.frame(year = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
n = c(0L, 53L, 40L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 180L, 118L, 137L, 6L, 14L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 145L, 49L, 0L, 5L, 47L, 304L, 104L, 127L, 15L, 25L, 
1L, 32L, 61L, 197L, 90L, 3L, 35L, 54L, 315L, 186L, 128L, 21L, 
47L, 35L, 79L, 67L, 282L, 91L, 17L, 130L, 58L, 396L, 248L, 133L, 
29L, 36L, 20L, 85L, 97L, 263L, 108L, 0L, 147L, 67L, 357L, 244L, 
130L, 28L, 43L, 13L, 130L, 97L, 284L, 150L, 0L, 180L, 90L, 490L, 
278L, 129L, 55L, 63L, 12L, 230L, 85L, 290L, 149L, 37L, 163L, 
122L, 491L, 373L, 140L, 72L, 98L, 13L, 327L, 83L, 300L, 190L, 
41L, 181L, 196L, 556L, 390L, 133L, 80L, 123L, 12L, 138L, 34L, 
116L, 75L, 0L, 91L, 117L, 259L, 179L, 81L, 15L, 77L, 0L, 0L, 
74L, 240L, 161L, 24L, 124L, 196L, 463L, 261L, 116L, 13L, 83L, 
0L, 165L, 5L, 11L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 40L), 
objectid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA))
```

I add an ID column to the sf object and merge it with my count data:

```
uk_map$objectid <- 1:12

uk_map_data <- merge(uk_map, yearCountsAllRegions, by = "objectid")
```

I am able to plot a faceted version:

```
ggplot(data=uk_map_data)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=n,geometry=geometry))+
  scale_fill_continuous(high = "#132B43", low = "white",
                        name="Number of\nOperations")+
  theme_void()+facet_wrap(~year)
```

However, if I try to animate this, I get an error:

```
ggplot(data=uk_map_data)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=n,geometry=geometry))+
  scale_fill_continuous(high = "#132B43", low = "white",
                        name="Number of\nOperations")+
  theme_void()+transition_time(time = year)
```

> Error: arguments have different crs

The same happens if I try to use transition_states:

```
ggplot(data=uk_map_data)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=n,geometry=geometry))+
  scale_fill_continuous(high = "#132B43", low = "white",
                        name="Number of\nOperations")+
  theme_void()+transition_states(year)
```

> Error: arguments have different crs
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In lapply(row_vars$states, as.integer) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 2: In expand_panel(..., self = self) : NAs introduced by coercion

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi. Saw your post on upwrok too :) Seems that this is a recent bug in gganimate: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/479

Comment: Can you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question? I'm able to run your code without any error.

Comment: R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

Comment: other attached packages:
 [1] plotly_4.10.1     gifski_1.6.6-1    tweenr_2.0.2      transformr_0.1.4  gganimate_1.0.8   rmapshaper_0.4.6  raster_3.6-20     lubridate_1.9.2   forcats_1.0.0     stringr_1.5.0    
[11] dplyr_1.1.1       purrr_1.0.1       readr_2.1.4       tidyr_1.3.0       tibble_3.2.1      tidyverse_2.0.0   sf_1.0-12         stringdist_0.9.10 gpclib_1.5-6      plyr_1.8.8       
[21] broom_1.0.4       rgeos_0.6-2       ggmap_3.0.2       ggplot2_3.4.1     rgdal_1.6-5       maptools_1.1-6    mapdata_2.3.1     maps_3.4.1        sp_1.6-0

Comment: loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-7        progress_1.2.2      httr_1.4.5          bslib_0.4.2         tools_4.2.3         backports_1.4.1     utf8_1.2.3          R6_2.5.1            KernSmooth_2.23-20 
[10] lazyeval_0.2.2      DBI_1.1.3           colorspace_2.1-0    withr_2.5.0         tidyselect_1.2.0    prettyunits_1.1.1   curl_5.0.0          compiler_4.2.3      textshaping_0.3.6  
[19] cli_3.4.1           geojsonsf_2.0.3     sass_0.4.5          labeling_0.4.2      scales_1.2.1        classInt_0.4-9      proxy_0.4-27

Comment: systemfonts_1.0.4   digest_0.6.31      
[28] foreign_0.8-84      rmarkdown_2.21      jpeg_0.1-10         pkgconfig_2.0.3     htmltools_0.5.5     fastmap_1.1.1       jsonvalidate_1.3.2  htmlwidgets_1.6.2   rlang_1.1.0        
[37] rstudioapi_0.14     httpcode_0.3.0      jquerylib_0.1.4     generics_0.1.3      farver_2.1.1        jsonlite_1.8.4      magrittr_2.0.3      Rcpp_1.0.10         munsell_0.5.0      
[46] fansi_1.0.4         lifecycle_1.0.3     terra_1.7-18        stringi_1.7.12      yaml_2.3.7          jqr_1.2.3           grid_4.2.3          parallel_4.2.3

Comment: geojsonio_0.11.0   [55] crayon_1.5.2        lattice_0.20-45     geojson_0.3.4       hms_1.1.3           knitr_1.42          pillar_1.9.0        geojsonlint_0.4.0   codetools_0.2-19    lpSolve_5.6.18     
[64] crul_1.3            glue_1.6.2          evaluate_0.20       V8_4.2.2            data.table_1.14.8   png_0.1-8           vctrs_0.6.1         tzdb_0.3.0          RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.3
[73] gtable_0.3.3        cachem_1.0.7        xfun_0.38           e1071_1.7-13        rsconnect_0.8.29    ragg_1.2.5          viridisLite_0.4.1   class_7.3-21        units_0.8-1        
[82] timechange_0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `crs` and `datum` parameters of your base map in the code. Something like this:

```
ggplot(data=uk_map_data)+
  geom_sf(aes(fill=n,geometry=geometry))+
  scale_fill_continuous(high = "#132B43", low = "white",
                        name="Number of\nOperations")+
  theme_void()+transition_time(time = year)+
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(uk_map_data), datum = NA)
```