# Error: arguments have different crs in gganimate

Tags: r, gganimate

I am trying to plot a map using gganimate, however, I keep getting `Error: arguments have different crs`.

This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(countrycode)
library(gganimate)
library(transformr)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
eurovision <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-05-17/eurovision.csv')

to_plot <- 
  eurovision |> 
  select(year, artist_country, section, winner) |> 
  mutate(winnings = case_when(
    str_detect(section, "^grand-final$|^final$") & winner == TRUE ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0)) |>
  rename(admin = artist_country) |> 
  left_join(world) |> 
  select(year, admin, winnings, geometry) |>
  arrange(year) |> 
  group_by(admin) |> 
  mutate(winnings = lag(cumsum(winnings), default = 0)) |> 
  ungroup()

to_plot |> 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = winnings, geometry = geometry)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-25, 50), ylim = c(30, 80), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 1) + 
  labs(title = "{frame_time}") + 
  transition_time(year)
```

I tried to transform the geometry to latitute and longitude but it did not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This appears to be a recent bug, my own code that worked fine a few weeks ago gets a similar error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75900914/problem-animating-with-geom-sf-and-gganimate-error-arguments-have-different-cr https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/479

Comment: That's what I imagined. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to using `gganimate` package, I would try to generate individual still images and combine those images into video or gif file.

R code to generate still images

```
get_map <- function(y) {
  to_plot |> filter(year == y) %>% 
      ggplot() + 
      geom_sf(aes(fill = winnings, geometry = geometry)) +
      coord_sf(xlim = c(-25, 50), ylim = c(30, 80), expand = FALSE) +
      scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 1, 
                           limits = c(0, 7)
                           ) + 
      labs(title = y) 
    }

y_list <- to_plot$year %>% sort %>% unique
my_maps <- paste0("~/temp/m_", seq_along(y_list), ".png")
for (i in seq_along(y_list)){
    get_map(y = y_list[i])
    ggsave(my_maps[i], width = 4, height = 4)
}
```

It is likely there are some R packages to combine images into a video, but I am comfortable with python `moviepy`:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
plist = [f"~/temp/m_{x}.png" for x in list(range(1, 68))]
anim = ImageSequenceClip(plist, fps = 20)
anim.write_gif("gif_map.gif") # or anim.write_videofile("vid_map.mp4")
```

Although this approach needs a little bit more code, but it can be much more flexible than using an existing animation package.
Due to size limit, the follow gif only included the last 29 images.
[image]